# How to prove these 6 functions to be continuous?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Functions:

$ f(x) = c  \\  f(x) =x \\ f(x) = e^x \\ f(x) = ln(x) \\ f(x) = sin(x)\\f(x) = \lvert x \rvert$

Please use the delta-epsilon definition of continuity to prove these.

Edit:

My proof for f(x) = c

Theorem: 
limit of x-> 0 of c

$Want\;to\;show: \forall \epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,s.t.\lvert x \rvert < \delta \Rightarrow \lvert c-c\rvert<\epsilon \\ Let \;\epsilon>0\\Take\;\delta=\cfrac{\epsilon}{10}\\Assume\;\lvert x \rvert < \delta\\\mathrm{Therefore, \;since\;0\leq \lvert x \rvert < \delta\;,\lvert c-c\rvert\leq\lvert x \rvert < \delta\leq\epsilon}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Yeah but I want to see how they are through a rigorous proof. I’m really bad at writing proofs.

Comment: Can you try to write out the proof for $f(x)=c$, where $c$ is a constant? The best way we can answer is to see what your misunderstanding is, if any.

Comment: I updated the OP

Answer (score 2):

That proof went very well. Note that $\delta=\epsilon$ works. The "since" part is redundant. Now you should try with $f(x)=x$. Which would be the $\delta$?

Comment: I can't figure this one out. How would you do it?

Comment: @user2793618 Choose $\delta=\epsilon$. If $0\leq|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|x-x_0|< \delta=\epsilon$.

The next one should be $f(x)=\sin(x)$ but it would be better for you to see it on a book. Since you are at level 0 (in $\epsilon-\delta$ argument) I recommend you to look at proof on books and youtube.

Comment: I suppose I was confused on what to pick for a in the x-> a part of the limit. Are those things I can define?

Comment: @user2793618 First, read the definitions of limit and continuity. Understanding them is crucial. Knowing what you have and what yo want to prove is basic. There is your answer about choosing "a".